# php inWarning: include_once error while deploying website

Tags: php, deployment, wampserver

While deploying a php website on wamp server, im getting the Warning: include_once(includes/xyz.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\x\index.php on line 2
can somebody help?

Comment: Have u included the File?or Have u given the file name with right capitalization?

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message, that was really helpful.